# why does this readstream is not being sent as a express result?

Tags: node.js

im using ytdl-core to get audio stream and using it in my code like this

```
let stream;
let v_id;

app.get("/ytid/:videoId", function (req, res) {
  let inputVideoID = req.params.videoId;
  getAudio(inputVideoID, res)
    .then(() => {
      stream.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
});

async function getAudio(videoID, res) {
  if (videoID != v_id) {
    console.log(`getAudio: ${videoID}`);
    stream = ytdl(videoID, {
      quality: "lowestaudio",
      filter: "audioonly",
    });
    v_id = videoID;
  }
}
```

but the audio is not being sent. if i want to pipe the result straight from the `getAudio()` function to the `res`, it will be fine, but i want to cache it and send the cached stream to multiple people. is there something wrong with the way im handling my streamDatas?

Comment: First of all, are you sure the `getAudio()` executes successfully? What did you get when `console.log(stream)` in `then()` callback? Try to debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream in node.js are not reusable. When read or written, they consumed. That is, once you've read data from a stream once,you can't read it again, Therefore, you cannot use the same stream to process multiple requests

I write an example to get audio from youtube:

```
const express = require('express');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const Stream = require('stream');

let buffer;
let v_id;

const app = express();

app.get("/ytid/:videoId", function (req, res) {
  let inputVideoID = req.params.videoId;
  getAudio(inputVideoID)
  .then((buffer) => {
    const stream = new Stream.PassThrough();
    stream.end(buffer);
    stream.pipe(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  });
});

async function getAudio(videoID) {
  if (videoID !== v_id || !buffer) {
    console.log(`Audio ID: ${videoID}`);
    const stream = ytdl(videoID, {
      quality: "lowestaudio",
      filter: "audioonly",
    });
    buffer = await streamToBuffer(stream);
    v_id = videoID;
  }

  return buffer;
}

function streamToBuffer(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
    stream.on('error', reject);
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

[image]

Comment: hi, a few question, in your code this buffer can be used how many times i want, right? but the down thing i noticed is that it looks like for the first time i have to wait for the whole readstream to be buffered then i can send that to the endpoint user, am i right? while if i just pipe the ytdl() return, i can send it instantly if im not wrong

Comment: @shiyonsufa, yes,your understanding is correct